# Is There an Alternative to PulseAudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've experienced many problems with pulseaudio one of which my bluetooth headphone never works properly after it wakes from the idle mode if there are no sounds for a while. I even tried to go to

```
/etc/pulse/
```

and comment out the line

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

in the file named `default.pa` as suggested by someone here.

But even though this partially fixed my headphone issue, I got microphone issues instead.

Is there an alternative to pulseaudio? If yes, how to install and use it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of uninstalling PulseAudio as suggested by Pabi you should disable autospawning by editing `/etc/pulse/client.conf` and replacing:

```
; autospawn = yes
```

with

```
autospawn = no
```

After that either reboot your machine or run `pulseaudio -k`, then and continue configuring ALSA.

Comment: I already uninstalled PulseAudio, but I reinstalled it right now using `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`. Hopefully, this is still a valid answer! I'm gonna try that!

Comment: By the way, `autospawn = no` without the prefixing semicolon, right?

Comment: @KareemMesbah Correct, you need to "uncomment" the line so that it will be read as part of the configuration, which will stop the service from spawning pulseaudio processes.

Comment: What about the sound tray? After uninstalling PulseAudio at first, it's gone! And now even though I re-installed it, it's still missing!

Comment: The Sound Menu (aka `indicator-sound`) depends on PulseAudio (and should be reappearing once PulseAudio is running), you have to find another application or indicator that does not depend on PulseAudio. I'm sorry, I cannot help you out with that.